# What would King Charles III's "short name" be?

Tags: united-kingdom, monarchy

Historically, until partway through Elizabeth II's reign, each monarch had a short name that was listed on legislation. Such as Eliz. II, Geo. III, etc...

For Charles II, different sources show different answers. I've seen Car. II, Cha. III, and Chas. III.

I know that monarchs don't use these anymore, but if Charles did, which would be the likely format?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It’s not really specific to the monarch, but to the person writing the citation. The more traditional citations tend to use the Latin ‘Car.’, while those preferring the more modern style use ‘Chas.’ or ‘Cha.’. As the British Library [explains](https://www.bl.uk/britishlibrary/%7E/media/subjects%20images/government%20publications/pdfs/primary-legislation.pdf?la=en), Charles is not the only regnal name with these variations:

> To a lesser extent, there may be variants of abbreviations of the sovereign’s name – James, Charles and William are usually abbreviated as Jac., Car. and Gul. (for Jacobus, Carolus and Guliemus) but Jas., Chas. and Wm (or Will) can also be used.

For what it’s worth, the [Chronological Table of the Statutes](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/changes/chron-tables/private) - which I suppose is as close to official as you can get - now prefers Cha.

As you alluded to in your question, for King Charles III, this is now rather academic, as since the passage of the [Acts of Parliament Numbering and Citation Act 1962](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Eliz2/10-11/34) (or 10 & 11 Eliz. 2 c. 34), acts are referred to based on calendar year, rather than the year of the sovereign’s reign.

Comment: But note Iacobus (on coins) is more traditional Latin,  and James 1st used the monogram IR

Answer (score 4):

For Consistency with the past, the abbreviation would be "Cha III". Here is a [list of all the abbreviations](https://www.lawfoundation.org.nz/style-guide2019/appendix-5.html) used in the past

This was used historically for [regnal years,](https://lawi.org.uk/regnal-years/) a dating system for laws. It isn't used in the 21st century in the UK.